# Does libgd use the GPU or the CPU by default?

Tags: linux, cpu, processing, gpu, images

http://www.libgd.org/ is the library's website.

I can find out on my own and post the details here later, but if anyone knows off hand it would save me a bit of time today I really need for other work.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would expect that kind of software (image *file* creation software) to be processed by the CPU as it is neither a very computationally intensive task nor does it need or really benefit from any GPU based computation.

If it were creating dynamic images that update at 60 frames per second or render CGI films  then *maybe* it might benefit from GPU acceleration, but all it is doing is doing some basic image conversion and then wrapping it in a container format.

It says it is written in C, which is generally just a CPU programming language.  If it were GPU based I would expect mention of [CUDA](http://www.nvidia.com/object/cuda_home_new.html) or the ATI equivalent.

Comment: I know it is overkill to some extent but it would be an interesting project. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, I didn't actually know GPUs use a different language.